# writing Operation logs using the Servlet Filters

Tags: java, logging, servlets, servlet-filters, operation

We want to write operation logs in our application for all the operation being made to DataBase. The operation log should contain the operation info(the data being "add/modify/delete") and the result of the operation(success/failure).
Since there are more number of action classees, adding the code to write operation log in each  action class looks difficult. So I thought of writing this part of code in the Servlet Filter.
But I have a problem here, I need to know the operation status(success/failure) but this is not possible in the filter with out parsing the response object. But parsing the response object looks difficult.
Can you suggest any alternative way to do this?

Thanks,

Chandra

Answer (score 0):

If your application is AOP-based like Spring, then you can define aspects which can check for criteria like classes of a particular package, methods of a particular type (get/set/both). Using these aspects you can add logging.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to achieve this is to add some extra logging to the JDBC driver. In the past I used [Log4JDBC](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/) project.